# Demonsteel Questline WOW

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Are there any specific requirements as far as what level you are in blacksmithing in order to get the quest " The Art of Demonsteel"?

I went to the Iron Horn Enclave in High Mountain and tried to talk to the blacksmithing trainer, "Muirn Ironhorn" but he has nothing to say to me about the quest. Are there some pre-quests I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

The art of Demonsteel is the 33rd quest in a 34 quest chain. If you didn't cancel or forget any quests you can simply open your questlog and complete the quests in the "Blacksmithing" tab. This will automatically continue the quest chain for you.

If you have skipped or cancelled a quest the only thing you can do is guess which one it was. Sometimes you'll see a yellow exclamation mark if you open the world map but it could also be that you have to remember where you left off.

[**Here**](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=38833/the-art-of-demonsteel#comments:id=2366549) you can find a Wowhead comment with all the quests in the chain. Theseare as follows:

```
ID   Quest                              Zone    
1    Strange New Ores                   Dalaran 
2    The Properties of Leystone         Dalaran 
3    The Methods of the Nightfallen     Azsuna          
4    Hatecoil Hammerwork                Azsuna      
5    Engineers: Not COMPLETELY Useless  Dalaran         
6    Chicken Scratch                    Dalaran         
7    Secrets of Leysmithing             Dalaran         
8    Nature Provides                    Dalaran 
9    Leysmithing Mastery                Dalaran  
10   Flower-Pickers and Potion-Quaffers Dalaran         
11   The Highmountain Smiths            Highmountain            
12   You Are Not Worthy                 Highmountain        
13   Ironhorn Leysmithing               Highmountain     
14   Grayheft                           Highmountain     
15   From One Master to Another         Dalaran         
16   Not Just Weapons and Armor         Dalaran         
17   Leystone Hoofplates                Dalaran  
18   Legend of Black Rook Hold          Val'sharah          
19   Between the Hammer...              Val'sharah   
20   ...And the Anvil                   Val'sharah          
21   The Knowledge of Black Rook        Dalaran         
22   A Sweet Bargain                    Dalaran         
23   Advanced Quenching                 Dalaran  
24   Felsmith Nal'ryssa                 Suramar         
25   Part of the Team                   Suramar         
26   Smith Under Fire                   Suramar     
27   Nal'ryssa's Technique              Suramar     
28   Leystone's Potential               Suramar 
29   The Firmament Stone                Highmountain            
30   Leystone Mastery                   Highmountain    
31   Hammered By The Storm              Maw of Souls     
32   Worthy of the Stone                Highmountain            
33   The Art of Demonsteel              Highmountain     
34   Tribal Knowledge                   Suramar
```

**You need level 110 or higher in blacksmithing in order to start [Leystone mastery](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=38531/leystone-mastery#comments)**